# I mapped networked drives with GPO but users are not seeing networked drives?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I followed the instructions here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/01/07/using-group-policy-preferences-to-map-drives-based-on-group-membership.aspx

I successfuly mapped drives but when users login they still have to add the networked drives manually.

I've tried tons of settings for the past few hours but nothing is working. Advice? I did notive a yellow triangle next to each mapped drive in the GPO editor for mapped drives.

Win server 2008

Answer (score 0):

GPO not applying to all in OU or even at the top domain level.

Somethings I have noticed and also suspect.

You cannot assign a drive in use ( typical error needing one of the following performed)

1. Use another drive map letter in GPO or `NET USE (whateverdriveLetter:)`
2. If drives is already mapped on the network run `NET USE (WhateverDriveLetter:) /D /Y`
   (the /d /y is delete or unmap that drive and /y = the auto response to the Y/N prompt
3. This 3rd one is an issue that I am suspecting , there are card readers that are assigned local system drive letter and hog up letters , ie those nasty 41-in-1 card readers that take up 7-12 drive letters - ridiculous.
4. Look for Norton AV or another end-point-management or security software installed on end systems, it may be blocking GPO roll out

Also on windows XP "auto" mappign via a batch may work fine but Vista and newer may have issues with CMD.exe not allowing UNC paths. Now the following is my solution to THAT issue.

create a batch file, and before the entry that runs

```
net use X: \\computername\folder\ /persistent:yes
```

insert (all on the same line):

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v DisableUNCCheck  /t REG_DWORD /d 00000001 /f
```

Notice the `/d 00000001` . that is what tweaks the UNC check off and on. To turn it back on make sure it reads 00000000.

so in essence it is the question `DisableUNCCheck=1`  and as we all should know 0=no and 1=yes off Off / ON ( it just depends in if you reverse the logic :)

You **do not** want some Coffey? Yes/1
 would be the same as:
**Do** you want any Coffey? = No/0

What is inverse or backwards logic is often used in MS programming to skirt around some issues, other times it's just backwards to make it hard to remember or to just figure out on one's own.